# Dynamic list of content URL for Cordova apps

Tags: android, cordova

Is there a way to modify the Cordova source, or is there any plugins, that allows for configurable and dynamic loading of content URLs for hosted web apps?

**Why is this needed?**

I would like to be able to connect the same compiled app to different endpoints, e.g. "test-server" and "production-server", without having to build individual .apk files.

Already using the "cordova-plugin-hostedwebapp", with client loaded plugins and app loaded from remote server.

**Possible solution?**

One possible solution could perhaps be to have a known endpoint, e.g. "startup.domain.com" which returns some HTML content that allows users to select which endpoint to navigate to, e.g. "localhost", "test-server", "production-server". And then store some key in local storage, which will automatically redirect the user on next launch (and then have option to pick another server in some options dialog).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Microsoft Code Push](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/).

Reading the docs should give you an overview of what it can do, f.e. [about managing different channels](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/docs/cli.html#link-4) like test and production. I guess it could meet your needs and is [accepted by the app stores](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/faq/index.html#1-does-the-apple-app-store-allow-developers-to-perform-these-types-of-updates).